# HTML <meta> tag

Tags: html, servlets

I am reading a Servlet "HellowWorld" tutorial. The servelet is defined in a HelloWorldServelet.java class. Super simple to output "Hell world" message to the client request. The only html file is "index.html" below. I don't understand how the meta tag works. As I run the application in the web server, it automatically this page with the URL:

http://localhost:8080/helloworld/HelloWorld

How the attributes "http-equiv" and "content" work together with the servelet?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=HelloWorld">
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Warning: such a tutorial is likely of poor quality. There are better ways to have a servlet as home page than abusing a welcome file with a meta refresh.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, just for learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Refresh` meta-tag automatically redirects the browser to the URL given after the specified amount of time.

Without seeing the tutorial you are using, I can't imagine why you would need to use it for your task.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Answer (score 2):

`"http-equiv"` and `"content"` 
they are used for adding message headers in http response .

For example `http-equiv` can be used to refresh the page. 
if you specify something like this

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="45">
```

you are instructing browser to refresh in every 45 seconds.

Other than `refresh`,you can use it to set `cookies` and etc.